# REST API is always throwing 404 error in Spring boot maven multimodule project with H2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring boot and I have created a multi-module project(maven) with spring boot. And I created some REST APIs and connected to H2 database.
The database is connected successfully and able to run in localhost.

This is my project tree.. User-Management is parent and core, serverAPI are child modules. And I have created packages for each module and added the relevant classes.

I have tried everything I know and searched google for like 5 days but nothing worked for me. I have included every code I wrote here. Please help me to find what the issue is.
(I am using intellij idea 2020.3 ultimate)

[image]

User.java

```
package com.hms.usermanagement.core.model;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "full_name")
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

public User() {
}

public User(long id, String fullName, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.email = email;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package com.hms.usermanagement.core.repository;

import com.hms.usermanagement.core.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
 }
```

**Application**

```
package com.hms.usermanagement.serverAPI.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
}}
```

**UserController**

```
package con.hms.usermanagement.serverAPI.controller;


import com.hms.usermanagement.core.model.User;
import com.hms.usermanagement.core.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

//Create Users
@PostMapping("/user")
public User createUser( @Validated @RequestBody User user){
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

//View all Users
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

//Update Users
@PutMapping("/users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity <User> updateUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") long userId , @RequestBody User userDetails){
    Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
    if(user.isPresent()){
        User _user = user.get();
        _user.setFullName(userDetails.getFullName());
        _user.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.save(_user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

//Delete Users
@DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") long userId){
    userRepository.findById(userId);
    userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

#enable H2 console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

#custom H2 console
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

**schema-h2.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE users (id long PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, full_name VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(50));
```

**I have tried using both these 2 urls**
[image]

[image]

Even "id" field is auto generated but I tried to add id also using postman.. But still getting the same error
[image]

Comment: check this out: https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-component-scan

Comment: Already tried that too

Comment: can you improve your question with the latest code or add it here?

Comment: Why your project is broken into two parts? That way they are totally different spring boot applications.

Comment: @Aristotle I created it as multi module project

Comment: Yes but that way your controller, repository, and model are in different projects, and you cannot manage them together. That's why you cannot map the request to an appropriate controller.

Comment: well, the application.java file location can be at the root level of the project

Comment: Yes maybe if you specify it at the parent pom.xml this will work without any issue.

Comment: @Deepika When somebody says "Stupid question, but...", they mean "I have a stupid question, and it is...". They're referring to their own question, not yours. This is a common North American idiom.

Comment: @Deepika - Do you have `server.servlet.contextPath=/` defined in your spring boot application.properties by any chance? If not, can you please try to add it to your properties file? Most probably, 404 not found is thrown because your application is confused about where to start searching for the URL pattern that you give in PostMan

Comment: @Deepika - N.B - The above change may be done in addition to the suggestions by Ismail related to ComponentScan and package for Application.java.

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran Sure thankyou. I'll try this too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your Sprint boot runner class, `Application` class is under `com.hms.usermanagement.serverAPI.application` package, so Spring boot will only scan the components under `com.hms.usermanagement.serverAPI.application`. So your core and web components are not recognized by Spring boot.

To solve the issue try to move `Application.java` class under `com.hms.usermanagement`.

Or you can customize the component scan by adding`@ComponentScan` annotation to `Application.java` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.hms.usermanagement")
```

Comment: I created it as multi-module project. If I remove it an change the file to some where I think it won't be a multi module project

Comment: No problem, you just need to rename the package in the same project location. Spring boot analyzes the classpath at runtime, all the project modules will be gathered in the same Jar file.

Comment: I have tried @ComponentScan. But still getting the same result

Comment: Try the other solution so, it will work certainly. in the same project serverAPI, rename the package com.hms.usermanagement.serverAPI.application to com.hms.usermanagement.

Comment: I'll try that too

Comment: Since you are using Intellij, it's simple, right click above the package -> refactor -> rename.

Comment: I have changed the package as com.hms.usermanagement. But still getting the 404 error

Comment: hi @Deepika, did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I did a new maven: `mvn clean verify` of the project and the issue was solved.

Answer (score -1):

Remove @Validated and try @Valid as below

Calling with [LOCALHOST]:[PORT]/api/user

```
//Create Users
@PostMapping("/user")
public User createUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user){
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. But when i try to add @Valid I am getting error -> Cannot resolve symbol 'Valid'

Comment: Add below dependancy!
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: No. All requests are giving 404. I already have that dependency

Comment: hey, please edit your question with server logs during runtime and pom.xml if possible.